# Make part of a text a hyperlink in Word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need to update an old Word macro. This macro creates a table in the footer with 2 cells.
The first cell contains the address and the website url:

```vb
With myTable
    .Cell(1, 1).Range.text = Line1 & vbCrLf & Line2 & vbCrLf & URL
End With
```

I need to make the URL a proper hyperlink instead of just plain text.
I already found:

```vb
ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=???, Address:= "http://myurl.com"
```

But I can't figure out what to put as the Anchor. I tried working with the `Selection` object but its `.Execute` doesn't returns anything.

Please advice.

Comment: Did you look it up in the VBA help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.hyperlinks.add

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of code would do the job you describe.

```
Dim Line1 As String, Line2 As String
Dim Url As String
Dim Rng As Range

Line1 = "Line 1"
Line2 = "Line 2"
Url = "www.Mydot.com"

With ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(1, 1).Range
    .Text = Line1 & vbCrLf & Line2 & vbCrLf & Url
    Set Rng = .Paragraphs(3).Range
    Rng.MoveEnd Count:=-1
    .Hyperlinks.Add Rng, Rng.Text
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

The anchor is the object to which you are attaching the hyperlink. If we assume that's the text in the table cell, then try this:

```
Sub AddHyperlink()
    With ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(1, 1).Range
        .Text = "Line1" & vbCrLf & "Line2" & vbCrLf
        .Hyperlinks.Add ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(1, 1).Range, "http://www.brandwares.com"
    End With
End Sub
```

If it's just part of the text, you would first have to define a range that includes just the text you want, then use that range as the anchor.